# Android change size programmatically

Tags: android, button, height, width

I need to change the size of the buttons programmatically.
I read some answers and I do the next to change the button size.

```
button.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 50));
```

This code change the size correctly but the problem is that the button not stay in the position I want, it moves the button to the top left corner.

I need to change the button size but I don't want to change de position.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the existing RelativeLayout Rules as well,i.e whether the item is center aligned,align parent left etc. Or you can make use of the existing Params and modify the width and height as follows the RelativeLayout rules will not be modified.

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width=150;
        layoutParams.height=50;
```

Comment: but if i have like 10 buttons, i have to do the same for those ten? There is nothing generic?

Comment: Use some other layout as your parent layout...maybe a linearLayout

Answer (score 1):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 500;
params.height = 500;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```